# How to .. batch file which executes information in a text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, text-files

Sorry not much experience with batch files hence help needed please! ;-)

I'm working in a DOS box on a Windows 7 64 bit system.

I want to run an application as a batch file, but reading the information it needs from a text file which can be updated/amended regularly.

The syntax of the basic application is:

```
appname "variable" (the variable MUST be enclosed in quotes)
```

Successive variables can be concatenated to the following single line format:

```
appname "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4" ... etc
```

So I've created a batch file containing the above. However, this is unweildy when it comes to updating. Sometimes I omit the delimiting quotes which creates problems in the execution of the batch file.

It seems to me that from an updating/amending point it would be easier to set up a text file, say text.txt which would contain the following information:

```
"var1"
"var2"
"var3"
"var4"
```

etc. on successive lines.

This would make it easier for me to update and also to ensure I don't omit the delimiting quotes.

The batch file would get the application to "read" the text file, execute the first variable, then the second etc all the way through to the end. But I'm not sure if this is possible and if so, how to get the batch file to read successive lines in the text file and use those variables.

As I said earlier, I've not much experience with batch files and don't have a clue how to do this! :-(

Help please, thanks

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
@echo off
set $textFile="test.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type %$textFile%') do appname.exe %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "batchline=appname"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25193799.txt) DO SET "batchline=!batchline! "%%~a""
ECHO(%batchline%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25193799.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The application line is merely `echo`ed for verification. Remove the `ECHO(` **after verification** to execute your application.

The data in the file need not have "enclosing quotes".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both responses, both different but good in their own way. I use a few different instances and I've decided to use the first response for the longer lists and the second one for shorter lists (that way I can check see if something is going wrong, because I might have missed the second delimiting quote in the text file.

Superb, thanks to you both.